# Python venv not installing packages under my virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-venv

I have created and activated a virtual environment with Python on my Linux installation (On my AWS EC2 instance). It says it's using the correct python interpreter when I run `which python3`. But nonetheless when I run `python3 -m pip install <package>` it's not there when I run pip freeze. It keeps installing to my global installation

Python3 installation

[image]

pip installation:

[image]

pip freeze:

[image]

I also get this error when I try to install without the `--user` flag:
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/flask_api/flask_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

Why is not actually using the interpreter and storing it where it needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

Why run 'which python' then run python3?  ... Try 'which python3' (even better, run 'type python3' because it could be an alias that bypasses your venv)

Comment: I did run `which python3` as you can see in the screenshot. Sorry I mistyped in the explanation

Comment: When I run `type python3` I get `python3 is hashed (/var/www/html/flask_api/flask_env/bin/python3)
`

Comment: Sorry. I have trouble reading pictures of text. ... Isn't that error message path in your venv? ... do you have write permissions there?

Comment: No problem, yes it is. And it looks like I don't. I just followed the suggestion and included the `--user` flag and it still doesn't install where it should

Answer (score 0):

Delete Your actual virtual environment. And try again by following the python [doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).